# Why does this code take so long to compile with g++?

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, compilation

Consider the following code:

```
template<int i> class A
{
    typedef A<i-1> B;
    B x, y;
};
template<> class A<0> { char m; };
int main()
{
    A<LEVEL> a;
}
```

When benchmarking its compilation by g++ by the following Bash command (with g++ 8.3.0)

```sh
for ((level=1; level<30; ++level)); do
    echo -n ${level},
    /usr/bin/time -f %U g++ -DLEVEL=$level test.cpp -o /dev/null
done
```

I get the following output:

```
1,0.03
2,0.03
3,0.04
4,0.04
5,0.04
6,0.04
7,0.04
8,0.04
9,0.03
10,0.04
11,0.02
12,0.04
13,0.02
14,0.03
15,0.04
16,0.05
17,0.05
18,0.08
19,0.11
20,0.20
21,0.35
22,0.67
23,1.30
24,2.52
25,5.02
26,10.23
27,19.96
28,40.30
29,80.99
```

So, compilation time is exponential in `LEVEL`. But if I change `B x, y;` to `B x[2];`, then compilation happens in constant time (~30 ms).

Why does it happen? I thought that, since the compiler knows that `B` is one and the same type for both `x` and `y`, it would take the same time as compiling `x[2]`. But for some reason it appears different.
Can I somehow force `B` to be realized (as opposed to simply aliased) so that g++ could create both variables just as easily as it created the array?

Comment: A technically correct but useless (for you) answer: patch the compiler.

Comment: Why would you post that here? Gcc has a bugzilla for reporting issues... Make sure you test with the latest version first though.

Comment: @MarcGlisse I hoped there might be a good explanation or a workaround. Not sure if it'd be considered a bug worth trying to fix if I reported it as such.

Comment: They even have a keyword "compile-time-hog" for cases where the compiler takes too long to compile, so yes they consider it worth fixing (which doesn't mean they will do it immediately). So especially if you can see another compiler that doesn't have the exponential behavior (so you know it is avoidable), please report it. Well maybe check if you see anything very similar in the database, but it is ok if you miss a non-obvious duplicate.

Comment: Same behavior on clang-1100.0.33.8, x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0

Comment: @Botje interestingly, clang 6.0.0-1ubuntu2 (tags/RELEASE_600/final) x86_64 doesn't show this slowdown (but crashes on `LEVEL=907`)

Comment: @MarcGlisse reported: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=91990

Comment: Try compiling with `-ftime-report` to get more information on where the time is spent.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin [here](https://pastebin.com/raw/3tLAxUPa)'s the report.

Answer (score 1):

Because there is a bug in your g++ instance. It should not, and as @Marc Glisse commented, you should report it (which you have done at the time of writing)

You might want to delete your question then.